# Registrar un nuevo usuario a la newsletter (GetResponse.com) desde mi pagina php

Tags: php, api, curl

En mi pagina al rellenar un formulario con Email y nombre se procede a registrar al usuario en la lista de correo, entre distintas fuentes he encontrado este código para llevar eso a cabo pero la función sendPostRequest parece no devolver nada o al menos se detiene la ejecución en esta. a que puede ser debido? Alguien que haya echo la conexión con GetResponse? no tiene por que ser este código puedo utilizar otro:

```
// Configuración de la API de GetResponse
$api_key = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'; // Tu clave de API de GetResponse
$campaign_id = 'zzzzz'; // ID de la campaña
// Datos del suscriptor
$email = $mailto;
$name = $name;
// Autenticación OAuth 2.0
$auth_url = 'https://api.getresponse.com/v3/token';
$auth_data = array(
    'username' => 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz',//usuario y contraseña generado para la conexion con otras aplicaciones
    'password' => 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
);
$auth_response = json_decode(sendPostRequest($auth_url, $auth_data), true);
if (isset($auth_response['access_token'])) {
    $access_token = $auth_response['access_token'];
    // Datos para la suscripción
    $data = array(
        'name' => $name,//nombre introducido en el formulario
        'email' => $email,//email introducido en el formulario
        'campaign' => array('campaignId' => $campaign_id)
    );
    $contact_url = 'https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts';
    $contact_response = json_decode(sendPostRequest($contact_url, $data, $access_token), true);
    if (isset($contact_response['contactId'])) {
        echo "Suscripción exitosa. ID del contacto: " . $contact_response['contactId'];
    } else {
        echo "Error en la suscripción: " . json_encode($contact_response);
    }
} else {
    echo "Error en la autenticación: " . json_encode($auth_response);
}
// Función para enviar una solicitud POST con cURL
function sendPostRequest($url, $data, $token = null) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if ($token) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
        ));
    }
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

En otras versiones del código me arrojaba errores, he ido arreglando errores pero al final, ya no arroja errores, simplemente no hace nada, debuggeando he llegado a que el error esta en la función sendPostRequest y hasta ahí he llegado.

He contactado con soporte de GetResponse y tampoco me han sabido responder.

Gracias de antemano